# Argument issue when using vb.net shell ()

Tags: vb.net, shell, process

I was trying to use shell function in vb.net to run a program and then write/export the result else where , **it works on win8** but not XP !! The command line prints this error

**'C:\Documents' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Press any key to continue . . .**

```
Dim save as String="C:\exported.txt"
Dim command As String = tempPath & "app.exe -f " & IO.Path.GetTempPath & "  -o " & save & "  & pause"

shell("cmd /c " & command, AppWinStyle.NormalFocus, True)
```

Comment: Put a break in your program on the shell(... line and then see what's in command. Post it here.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Process.Start(IO.Path.Combine(tempPath, "app.exe"), "-f """ & IO.Path.GetTempPath & """  -o """ & Save() & """  & pause")
```

Comment: did not work :/ , my script works perfect with win8 but xp !!!! i dont know why !!!

Comment: Provide us with your full code instead of partial codes, that wat we can check if anything else is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

You hace a folder in the command with a space in it (probably the documents and Settings folder). cmd.exe has no way of telling whether the space is in the file name or the end of the file name, unless you put the file name in "" - like "C:\doxuments and Settings..."

```
Dim command As String = tempPath & "app.exe -f \"" & IO.Path.GetTempPath & "\"  -o \"" & save & "\"  & pause"
```

(\" is intended to escape a " so that it translates to embedding a " in the string. I'm not sure what the VB syntax is.)

EDIT:

I think @Roy van der Velde below has the 'escaping correct. The final part not checked is tempPath. See my comment on the question.

Comment: sorry but it did not work  , i tried to escape but nothing working  , it's driving me crazy